# How to bind grid view data based on the dropdown list selected value

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, sql-server-2008, webforms

I have one drop down list to select student name.when i select a student name in the drop down list, grid view has to show details of selected name.
This  is my coding for this but it didn't display anything.

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MGLCOMConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
con.Open();
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT VALUE,VDESC FROM CSOPTFD WHERE OPTFIELD='WONO'AND VALUE LIKE '%" + customerddl.SelectedValue + "%'", con);
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
da.Fill(ds);
GridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
GridView1.DataBind();
```

this is my cs code to get the details of selected value.But it didn't any thing.

Comment: From where you calling this code...i mean do you have postback event for your dropdown list? can you check whether you are getting selectedvalue in debug?

Comment: am calling this fun when value is selected in drop down, also i enable the auto post back too true.i can able to get selected drop down list value in a label.

Answer (score 1):

`VALUE` is a [*reserved keyword*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189822.aspx) for T-SQL. Use it with square brackets like `[VALUE]`

And please use [*parameterized queries*](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/04/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death.html) instead. This kind of string concatenations are open for [*SQL Injection*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT [VALUE], VDESC FROM CSOPTFD WHERE OPTFIELD = 'WONO' AND [VALUE] LIKE '%' + @value + '%'", con);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@value", customerddl.SelectedValue);
```

Comment: yeah soner,value is my column name.it executed well in sql server

Comment: hi soner,i try this code but it didn't display anything.when i change above code like this "SELECT [VALUE], VDESC FROM CSOPTFD WHERE OPTFIELD = 'WONO' AND [VALUE] LIKE '%" + @value + "%'" it works but shows all values

Comment: hi soner, above coding not workin give me suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Have you bind Dropdown Correctly,like CustomerId , Text and after that are you calling this code from Selected_Index_Changed Event with PostBack True ?

Answer (score 0):

Try providing the code in a `try - catch` block. Use the `finally` block to closed the connection by using `con.Close();`

Also try closing the connection and then accessing the dataset for values.

```
SqlConnection con =null;
DataSet ds=null;
try
{
        con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MGLCOMConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT VALUE,VDESC FROM CSOPTFD WHERE OPTFIELD='WONO'AND VALUE LIKE '%" + customerddl.SelectedValue + "%'", con);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds);

}
catch(SQLException ex)
{

}
finally
{
     if(con!=null)
         con.Close();
}
GridView1.DataSource = ds;
GridView1.DataBind();
```